# Kubernetes: active job is erroneously marked as completed after cluster upgrade

Tags: kubernetes

I have a working kubernetes cluster (v1.4.6) with an active job that has a single failing pod (e.g. it is constantly restarted) - this is a test, the job should never reach completion.

- If I restart the same cluster (e.g. reboot the node), the job is properly re-scheduled and continues to be restarted
- If I upgrade the cluster to v1.5.3, then the job is marked as completed once the cluster is up. The upgrade is basically the same as restart - both use the same etcd cluster.

Is this the expected behavior when going to v1.5.x? If not, what can be done to have the job continue running?
I should provide a little background on my problem - the job is to ultimately become a driver in the update process and it is important to have it running (even in face of cluster restarts) until it achieves a certain goal. Is this possible using a job?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Post it on github kube channels.

Comment: Did you compare the output of `kubectl get job <name> -o yaml` before and after the upgrade in order to spot changes in the definition?

Comment: No, but it's a good question whether they differ - I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In v1.5.0 `extensions/v1beta1.Jobs` was deprecated in favor of `batch/v1.Job`, so simply upgrading the cluster without updating the job definition is expected to cause side effects.

See the Kubernetes [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v150) for a complete list of changes and deprecations in v1.5.0.

Comment: I never said I was using the `extensions/v1beta1.Jobs` - it is with `batch/v1.Job` that I'm having issues, but thanks for the pointer.

Comment: My bad, I answered assuming `batch/v1.Job` was introduced in v1.5.0, but it was introduced in v1.3.0.